# C#/Unity parse.com subclassing buggy?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

This is what [parse.com Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#objects-properties-and-methods) says about subclassing ParseObjects:

```
[ParseClassName("Armor")]
public class Armor : ParseObject
{
  [ParseFieldName("displayName")]
  public string DisplayName
  {
    get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
    set { SetProperty<string>(value); }
  }
}
```

**Problem #1**: The example is wrong; both methods require a `propertyName` param, so this is what I do instead

```
[ParseFieldName("seed")]
public int Seed {
    get { return GetProperty<int>("seed"); }
    set { SetProperty<int>(value, "seed"); }
}
```

**Problem #2**: Doing so, I get the following exception:

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object].ContainsKey (System.String key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-    classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:458)
Parse.ParseObject.ContainsKey (System.String key)
Parse.ParseObject.TryGetValue[Int32] (System.String key, System.Int32& result)
Parse.ParseObject.GetProperty[Int32] (Int32 defaultValue, System.String propertyName)
Parse.ParseObject.GetProperty[Int32] (System.String propertyName)
Example.get_Seed () (at Assets/Commons/Parse/Example.cs:10)
```

I don't have the parse source code so I can't debug through, but this looks like a bug to me (in a VERY basic API). So I wonder; am I doing anything wrong? I noticed there's also a `Get<T>()`, for whatever reason, but no luck with that either.

**Update:** I'm using Parse.Unity 1.6.2.0

Comment: The example is not wrong, the property name field has a default value of null, which the method uses the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to find out the name of the property you are trying to retrieve. Note though, that if you do pass in the property name it shouldn't break, but you should use the same case (`Seed` instead of `seed`).

Comment: So if it's not wrong, why is a `No overload for method 'GetProperty' takes 0 arguments` compile error thrown at me? And why should I use the same case? The C# name and parse name do not have to match, otherwise the annotation would be rather useless, also the example does exactly the same.

Comment: Probably you have an old version of Mono which doesn't support optional parameters.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `ParseFieldName` attribute, I'm talking about the name you pass into the get/set method as a parameter.

Comment: Me too, that's why the compile error says `GetProperty`

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I'm using VS2015

Answer (score 0):

It looks like propertyName field is case sensitive and it has to match with name of the property:

```
[ParseFieldName("Seed")]
public int Seed {
   get { return GetProperty<int>("Seed"); }
   set { SetProperty<int>(value, "Seed"); }
}
// Seed is capitalized in all occurrences above
```